# How to access attributes from subtypes

Tags: graphengine

I followed the [TSL documentation on attributes](https://www.graphengine.io/docs/manual/TSL/tsl-basics.html#attributes) and created two classes:

```
[GraphNode]
cell struct Fruit
{
    string color;
}

[GraphNode, BaseType : Fruit]
cell struct Apple
{
    string variety;
}
```

I used the generated code like this:

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
Console.WriteLine(apple.variety);
Console.WriteLine(apple.color);
```

The code can access the `variety` field, but cannot access the `color` field:

> 'Apple' does not contain a definition for 'color' and no extension method 'color' accepting a first argument of type 'Apple' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I access the inherited attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attributes do not have an intrinsic meaning apart from the meaning you attach to them. "BaseType" does not make Apple derive from Fruit. You can just ask in your code for the value of the attribute "BaseType" on your cell.

Comment: Are there any ways to properly subtype a cell, or should I copy the required attributes (e.g. `string`) to each subclass?

Comment: That is one wish I share with you. But as far as I know, you cannot subclass. I did it with copy, too.

Comment: I just read the recent paper [Bin Shao et al. "Trinity Graph Engine and its Applications." (Bulletin of the IEEE Computer Society Technical Committee on Data Engineering, 2017).](http://sites.computer.org/debull/A17sept/p18.pdf) and it explains quite well how Trinity works internally. This clarifies things *a lot*, so hopefully it will be useful for someone.